# JSON PHP server modified

Tags: php, json, laravel

The following is my JSON data.

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Name": {
      "FirstName": "Wilmer",
      "LastName": "Crona",
      "FullName": "Mr. Cameron Prosacco"
    },
    "Address": {
      "Address1": "84154 Vickie Burg Apt. 994",
      "Address2": "Suite 339",
      "ZipCode": "89080-0376"
    },
    "Phone": "316-269-7694 x1364"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Name": {
      "FirstName": "Mercedes",
      "LastName": "Kshlerin",
      "FullName": "Dr. Kellie Bashirian"
    },
    "Address": {
      "Address1": "12638 Cali Spurs",
      "Address2": "Suite 353",
      "ZipCode": "76622"
    },
    "Phone": "319-329-3169 x8848"
  }
]
```

Here is where I want my JSON like this: https://github.com/Zlob/php-json-server but in the method. The JSON file must one file and process only one JSON `(db.json).`

If my JSON file `json1.json , json2.json, etc.` How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't decode only first element, you can decode all and get first element only, [here is online compiler](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fad97ecfe127b9eb44ed3da859987fce5e2ba8d1)

```
<?php

$json = '[
{
    "id": 1,
     "Name": {
     "FirstName": "Wilmer",
     "LastName": "Crona",
     "FullName": "Mr. Cameron Prosacco"
   },
   "Address": {
     "Address1": "84154 Vickie Burg Apt. 994",
     "Address2": "Suite 339",
     "ZipCode": "89080-0376"
   },
   "Phone": "316-269-7694 x1364"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "Name": {
     "FirstName": "Mercedes",
     "LastName": "Kshlerin",
     "FullName": "Dr. Kellie Bashirian"
   },
   "Address": {
     "Address1": "12638 Cali Spurs",
     "Address2": "Suite 353",
     "ZipCode": "76622"
   },
   "Phone": "319-329-3169 x8848"
 }
]';
$data = json_decode($json);
$firstObject = $data[0];
var_dump($firstObject);
```

Comment: i want like in github link

Answer (score 0):

pass database name in url and set the db name in config. put all your json file inside db folder.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use Response;
use Config;
use JsonServer\JsonServer;

class JsonServerController extends Controller
{
    public function handleRequest($db, $uri)
    {
        $data = Request::all();                                            
        $method = Request::method();  

        $pathToJson = storage_path($db .'.json'); //if your path in inside storage folder of laravel

        Config::set('pathToDb', $pathToJson); //here we set db

        $jsonServer = new JsonServer();                                     
        $response = $jsonServer->handleRequest($method, $uri, $data);       

        $response->send();                                                 
    }
}
```

Now define in routes

```
Route::any('api/{db}/{all}', "JsonServerController@handleRequest")->where('all', '.*');
```

Now the request will be like this for json1 database

```
GET    api/json1/posts
POST   api/json1/posts
PUT    api/json1/posts/1
PATCH  api/json1/posts/1
DELETE api/json1/posts/1
```

For json2 database

```
GET    api/json2/posts
POST   api/json2/posts
PUT    api/json2/posts/1
PATCH  api/json2/posts/1
DELETE api/json2/posts/1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177775/discussion-on-answer-by-rkj-json-php-server-modified).